# How to create Dynamic Routes

Tags: 8, routes, services

I have been trying to create dynamic routes by using RouteSubscriberBase class.

I know we can create dynamic routes by using slug parameter in the URL. Similar to this method ( https://befused.com/drupal/dynamic-route ).

But I want is dynamic Routes not URLs.Similar to this method ( https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/dynamic-routes-drupal-8-routesubscriber )

Here is the code I have written so far but I cant get whats missing in the code.

When I try to access http://example.com/custom-module/dynamic-routes/ it is available but when I try to access http://example.com/custom-module/dynamic-routes/tents I am getting Page not found Error.

I have Cleared cache before accessing the new URL.

**DynamicRoutesAlter.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * DynamicRoutesAlter Class.
 */
class DynamicRoutesAlter extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {

   $products = ['cooking_gear' => 'Cooking Gear', 'tents' => 'Tents' , 'sleeping_bags' => 'Sleeping Bags','rope' => 'Rope', 'safety' => 'Safety','packs' => 'Packs'];


    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {

      $url = preg_replace('/_/', '-', $key);

      $route = new Route(
        // The url path to match.
        '/custom-module/dynamic-routes/' . $url,
        // The defaults (see the custom_module.dynamic_routes for structure)
        [
          '_title' => $value,
          '_controller' => '\Drupal\custom_module\Controller\DynamicRoutesController::productType',
          'type' => $key, //Not sure what type does ? Is it required? I have seen it as the syntax in the book Mastering Drupal 8 By Chaz Chumley, William Hurley
        ],
        // The requirements.
        [
          '_permission' => 'create ' . $value,
        ]
      );

      // Add our route to the collection with a unique key.
      $collection->add('custom_module.dynamic_routes'. $key, $route);

    }
  }

}
```

**custom_module.services.yml**

```
services:
  custom_module.dynamic_routes:
    class: Drupal\custom_module\Routing\DynamicRoutesAlter
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

**custom_module.routing.yml**

```
custom_module.dynamic_routes:
  path: '/custom-module/dynamic-routes'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Dynamic Routes'
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_module\Controller\DynamicRoutesController::productType'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**DynamicRoutesController.php**

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function productType() {

    $build['results'] = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Controller to get Products List.'),
    ];

    return $build;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## DynamicRoutesAlter.php

### Problem #1 - preg_replace() without pattern

```php
$url = preg_replace('_', '-', $key);
```

The `$url` will be always `NULL`, because you are using `preg_replace()` without regexp, use instead `str_replace()` or write appropriate regexp pattern: `'/_/'`.

#### Solution #1

```php
$url = preg_replace('/_/', '-', $key);
```

#### Solution #2

```php
$url = str_replace('_', '-', $key);
```

### Problem #2 - wrong variable mixing

```php
$collection->add('custom_module.dynamic_routes'.{$key}, $route);
```

You are wrong with mixing variable and string. You want to concatenate it with the [curly syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex). This is also incorrect.

#### Solution #1

```php
$collection->add("custom_module.dynamic_routes.{$key}", $route);
```

#### Solution #2

```php
$collection->add('custom_module.dynamic_routes' . $key, $route);
```

After you fix those problems, your code will work.

I'm also not sure about `'type' => $key,`, why is that here? There is nothing about `type` route param.

P.s. as you mentioned itself, better use slugs.

## UPD - all files

Check your files for mistakes.

**custom_module.info.yml**

```
name: Custom module
type: module
description: For https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281728
package: Custom
core: 8.x
```

**custom_module.routing.yml**

```
custom_module.dynamic_routes:
  path: '/custom-module/dynamic-routes'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Dynamic Routes'
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_module\Controller\DynamicRoutesController::productType'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**custom_module.services.yml**

```
services:
  custom_module.dynamic_routes:
    class: Drupal\custom_module\Routing\DynamicRoutesAlter
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

**src/Controller/DynamicRoutesController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Returns responses for Custom module routes.
 */
class DynamicRoutesController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Builds response for dynamic routes.
   */
  public function productType() {

    $build['results'] = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Controller to get Products List.'),
    ];

    return $build;
  }

}
```

**src/Routing/DynamicRoutesAlter.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * DynamicRoutesAlter Class.
 */
class DynamicRoutesAlter extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {

    $products = ['cooking_gear' => 'Cooking Gear', 'tents' => 'Tents' , 'sleeping_bags' => 'Sleeping Bags','rope' => 'Rope', 'safety' => 'Safety','packs' => 'Packs'];


    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {

      $url = preg_replace('/_/', '-', $key);

      $route = new Route(
      // The url path to match.
        '/custom-module/dynamic-routes/' . $url,
        // The defaults (see the custom_module.dynamic_routes for structure)
        [
          '_title' => $value,
          '_controller' => '\Drupal\custom_module\Controller\DynamicRoutesController::productType',
          'type' => $key,
        ],
        // The requirements.
        [
          '_permission' => 'create ' . $value,
        ]
      );

      // Add our route to the collection with a unique key.
      $collection->add('custom_module.dynamic_routes' . $key, $route);

    }
  }

}
```

[image: Dynamic route]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer , but I need dynamic route Ids, so I can create dynamic menu items and tabs. So I need to proceed in this way. Those things you mentioned in the answer were my typos and I have corrected them. But I still cant get it working.

Comment: In the code, you provide there is no more place to mistake. I recreate your module and works as you expect it. Do you place files in the correct folders?
 Wait a min I think how to share code for you.

Comment: Check out the updated answer. I provide all my files used for testing.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and helping me. I did a silly mistake, In services.yml file I had used `custom_module.dynamic_routes` earlier for other service after renaming it all worked well.